Hybrid Exchange Online + standard webhosting bouncing emails
We are trying to configure a hybrid Exchange Online with another regular, old-fashioned hosting, where a few accounts (will be more with time) have Office 365, and the rest have a mailbox on the previous server.
At this point, we have our web hosting with Siteground, with around 150 users/mailboxes. Obviously the MX records point to Siteground and everything works.
What we want to achieve is to have all email get to Exchange Online and, if the mailbox is not found there, be redirected to SiteGround.
So, on Thursday evening, we start to perform the configuration changes, and this is what we do:

Set up a connector in Exchange Online, from Office 365 to
on-premises. a) We use the IPs SiteGround gave us for the MX records. b) After a few tries, the validation is successful and we receive the test emails
We set the domains to InternalRelay (in Exchange -> Accepted Domains)
We change the MX records to that of Exchange Online and update the SPF record
Test, test, test: a) External to 365 and to SiteGround; b) 365 to 365 and to SiteGround; c) SiteGround to external and to 365

After an hour or so, we decide that everything is working fine, and we call it a night. Next morning, at around 7:30 we start receiving a lot of complaints about customers reporting their emails are bouncing.
After analyzing Message Trace, we identify two different bounces. We didn’t know what to do next, so we reverted the MX records to SiteGround, and everybody was happy again… for now.
So, these are the two bounces:
Bounce #1 is issued by SiteGround, from a Exchange Online IP (the 104.47.66.43 – IP can change but reverse DNS is always Microsoft).


Bounce #2 is sent by Exchange Online and the details show ten hops:

The strange thing is that on Thursday evening everything worked fine (with a few emails), and it was until volume picked up Friday morning that we started getting these issues. We have no idea what to test next, and we fear that it we try again it will work fine for us and then again fail when all users start using it.
I know there are a lot of smart people here, so I am sure some of you will point us in the right way.
Thanks!

I found the relevant link for your first error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/ndr/fix-error-code-550-5-0-350-in-exchange-online
I found the relevant link for your second error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/mailflow/hop-count-exceeded-possible-mail-loop

Thank you for your comment. I had already seen the second one, but it refers to when you use a subdomin. It's not the case with us.
Regarding the first one, I see 550 5.0.350 is more of a generic, wrapper error. I will investigate further and comment here if I find something.
Thanks!

Is the problem solved? How was the follow-up test conducted?
